# Understanding Asymptotic Fourier Behaviour

Tags: fourier-analysis, asymptotics, fourier-transform, stability-in-odes

I've been struggling with understanding some key concepts on long term behaviour of Fourier modes.

Imagine I have a $N\times M$ system of cells with two quantities being measured by $x_{i,j}(t)$ and $y_{i,j}(t)$ which are governed a coupled of non-linear ODEs. After linearizing the system and using the discrete Fourier transform, the solution of the linearized problem is given by
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\tilde{x}_{j,k}(t)\\
\tilde{y}_{j,k}(t)
\end{pmatrix}
=\sum_{\bar{q}}\sum_{\bar{p}}e^{2\pi i (\bar{q}j+\bar{p}k)}\left(
v_{\bar{q},\bar{p}}^+e^{\lambda_{\bar{q},\bar{p}}^+t}+v_{\bar{q},\bar{p}}^-e^{\lambda_{\bar{q},\bar{p}}^-t}
 \right)
$$
where $v_{\bar{q},\bar{p}}^\pm$ and $\lambda_{\bar{q},\bar{p}}^\pm$ are the eigenvectors and eigenvalues associated to the Fourier modes $(\bar{q},\bar{p})=(q/N,p/M)$, respectively. These naturally depend on the linearizing matrix associated to the specific problem.

Now, I read that the dominant pattern for large $t$ is a superposition of modes and therefore, by looking at the fastest growing modes, the previous solutions asymptotically satisfy
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\tilde{x}_{j,k}(t)\\
\tilde{y}_{j,k}(t)
\end{pmatrix}\sim
\begin{pmatrix}
C_x\\C_y
\end{pmatrix}
\sum_{(\bar{q},\bar{p})}
e^{2\pi i (\bar{q}j+\bar{p}k)}
$$
where the sum is now made over the fastest growing modes $(\bar{q},\bar{p})$ and $C_x,C_y$ are constants.

What I don't understand is the following:

1. How do I conclude that, as $t\to\infty$, I can approximate the solution by this?
2. What is the relation between the constants $C_x$ and $C_y$ and the eigenvectors and eigenvalues?
3. Can $C_x$ and $C_y$ be complex?

I tried searching for answers, but I might be missing some algebraic trick or something essential about the asymptotic behaviour of the Fourier transforms and fast growing modes. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, I am not sure about the answers, but since there is no any I will help you as I can: part (a) is related I think to these properties of the Fourier transforms [Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma), the [Stationary Phase Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_phase_approximation), and the [Laplace's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method)... hope it helps you to find your anser.